# Clickable UISlider

Tags: objective-c, ios, uislider

I'd like to make my UISlider clickable - to change the value on click to "blank space", e.g. It's set to zero, I click in the middle of the slider and it will "jump" to the middle. Is there any way how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to propose something similar as jrtc27, but without subclassing: add a [`UI(Tap)GestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to the slider.

```
UISlider *slider = [[[UISlider alloc] init] autorelease];
//configure slider
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sliderTapped:)] autorelease];
[slider addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];


- (void)sliderTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *) gestureRecognizer.view;
    //setValue 
}
```

Comment: And how will I get the value from the spot I clicked on?

Comment: let me guess: you don't like to look up documentation, right? But a hint: [`locationInView:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-SW23) should help u. and there are tons of example codes for gesture recognizer on SO and on the web.

Comment: Nah, I am a newbie to cocoa, I grew up Java related languages, so I am used to methods such as get-, set-, is-, on- etc. which aren't used as much in Objective-C. Right now it's locationInView, which really seems logical, but I would be looking for something like...getLocationInView. I will get used to it, right now I am learning how to :)

Comment: +1: A better answer than mine, although mine supports iOS 3 (and 2...) :)

Comment: This doesn't really work for me as it seems to only detect clicks on the thumb and not on any part of the slider.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass it and then alter the -touchesBegan method. If the touch is sufficiently far away, call -setValue:, else call the super implementation (if you want it to always jump, you can just always call -setValue:).

Comment: Wow, seems complex for one functionality. Due to time pressure I believe I'll have to pass on that...Thank you though.