# How to detect that a UISlider has been tapped using RubyMotion?

Tags: iphone, ruby, uigesturerecognizer, uislider, rubymotion

I have UISlider:

```
slider = UISlider.alloc.initWithFrame([[20, 70)], [260, 40]])
```

I want to be able to detect when the user clicks on it and know where. I figure that I'd need to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` or something similar, but I am very new and clueless to all this.

I can get to find out when the slider is tapped with this:

```
slider.addTarget(self, action:'sliderTaped', forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown)
```

... but it only works on the thumb, so that's not very useful, I'd rather catch any tap on the slider.

Any pointers or links to documentation would be appreciated.

---

*Related question/answer, but with objective-c: [Clickable UISlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249510/clickable-uislider)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get notified when the slider has been changed, you need to set up the `target/action`.
The `target` is the object containing the method you want called, and the `action` is the
method you want called.  I called my `action` `sliderValueChanged:`.  You can choose anything.  Be sure to append the colon to the name because that tells it to send a pointer to the sender which is the `UISlider` object.  You need the sender so that you can ask for the value of the slider.

If you don't set a `minimumValue` and `maximumValue` for the slider, the values will range from `0.0` to `1.0`.

```
def viewDidLoad
    slider = UISlider.alloc.initWithFrame([[20, 70], [260, 40]])
    slider.addTarget(self, action:'sliderValueChanged:', forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged)
    self.view.addSubview(slider)
end

def sliderValueChanged(sender)
    puts sender.value
end
```

As shown, `sliderValueChanged` will get called continuously as the user moves the slider.  To be notified only when the user stops touching the slider, set:

```
slider.continuous = no
```

Now, if you want a clickable slider that moves the thumb to where you click, then you need to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the slider.  This code demonstrates this:

```
def viewDidLoad
    slider = UISlider.alloc.initWithFrame([[50, 50], [200, 40]])
    tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.alloc.initWithTarget(self, action:'sliderTapped:')
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    slider.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    slider.continuous = false
    slider.minimumValue = 77
    slider.maximumValue = 129
    slider.addTarget(self, action:'sliderValueChanged:', forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged)
    self.view.addSubview(slider)
end

# This is called when the slider changes either from taps or from moving the thumb
def handle_new_slider_value(value)
    puts "New slider value: #{value}"
end

def sliderValueChanged(slider)
    handle_new_slider_value(slider.value)
end

# These were determined empirically by setting the thumb to the minimum and
# then clicking on the center and printing out gestureRecognizer.locationInView(slider).x
# and then repeating for the maximum.
SLIDER_MIN = 11
SLIDER_MAX = 189

def sliderTapped(gestureRecognizer)
    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
        slider = gestureRecognizer.view
        x = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(slider).x
        # Uncomment this to determine values for SLIDER_MIN/SLIDER_MAX
        # puts x
        x = SLIDER_MIN if x < SLIDER_MIN
        x = SLIDER_MAX if x > SLIDER_MAX
        slider_min_val = slider.minimumValue
        slider_max_val = slider.maximumValue

        # Convert from the location in the view to the slider value
        slider.value = slider_min_val + (x - SLIDER_MIN) / (SLIDER_MAX - SLIDER_MIN) * (slider_max_val - slider_min_val)
        handle_new_slider_value(slider.value)
    end
end
```

Note that this code moves the slider on a double tap.  I had trouble with just a single tap because if you move the thumb quickly, the code treats it as a tap and snaps the thumb back to its starting position.  Set `tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1` to play around with the single tap.

Comment: I see now that you were wanting the slider to jump to the point the user touched.  I'll try to figure that out and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But yes, I want to find how to jump to the point touched, not get the change that occured (this is documented a bit).

Comment: If you figure that out that'd be tremendously helpful!